# First time using scp -r before and I keep getting an error "Host Key verification error"

Tags: c++, bash, scp, robotics

I've never used the bash language before (is scp -r part of bash?) and there's a C++ Xcode file I want to copy to a different IDE (more specifically for a robot controller). That C++ file is in a folder, and I heard that you use `scp -r` for folders? So I tried using that: `scp -r Desktop/oroni-club/gyro.cpp root@192.168.124.1:"[path]"`

The host key is the IP address of the controller, and I'm not quite sure what `"[path]"` is, someone just told me to use that.

I also keep getting this error: `Host key verification failed.
lost connection`, and it doesn't end up copying the C++ file to the other IDE.

I'm not sure what to do and how to copy a C++ file to this other non C++ IDE (this one only offers C and Python, but you can still add a C++ file using bash through the terminal), I'm completely new to this...

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

“Host key verification failed” means that the host key of the remote host was changed since you ssh to it in last time and so the system does not allow access for security purposes. So you need to change the host key in the known_hosts file.

https://mycyberuniverse.com/linux/how-to-fix-host-key-verification-failed.html